# TableViewCell leads to a Single View Controller with different details SWIFT

Tags: swift, uitableview

Everything works here but my question is I am trying to access different information with different cell that I press. For example:

If you press on first table view cell which contains:

**A** --> Second View with information containing **A Image** and name of **A**

If you press on second table view cell which contains:

**B** --> Second View with information containing **B Image** and name of **B**

If you press on third table view cell which contains:

**C** --> Second View with information containing **C Image** and name of **C**

If you noticed that on my FirstViewController, the information & informationArray is outside of the class because i intend to access those information on SecondViewController. However, that doesnt matter much just in case you are curious.

---

**Things That I have tried:**

- I have tried writting each information manually on different view controller however I notice that would increase the size of the App since I have information that is over 100 and that would mean creating more than 100 viewcontroller. Also involve using segue right here
- Tried calling the array from the second view controller, and that result in showing all **A** in any of the cell pressed, which I haven figure out what is the best way to do.
- Tried googling & youtubing & stackoverflowing and still couldnt find any help that I needed so I decided to post this up.

**MyStruggle or What I want to achieve:**

As written above, I Would like some help/technique that you know can help me to figure out a way to, with different tableviewcell that I pressed, it shows information stored on those array respectively.

If you noticed, I trying to use one view controller instead of multiple view controller.

FirstViewController.swift

```
struct information {
   var name: [String]!
   var image: [UIImage]!
init(named: [String], imaged: [UIImage]){
name = named
image = imaged
}
    }

var informationArray = [information]()

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad(){
informationArray = [information(name: ["A","B","C"],
                    image: [UIImage(named: "A"),UIImage(named:"B"),UIImage(named: "C")]

     }

}
```

SecondViewController.swift

```
class SecondViewController: UITableViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var Image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Name: UITextField!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UITableView comes with several built-in methods for free to help accomplish exactly what you are trying to do. Here is a tutorial explaining some of the concepts:

http://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-uitableviewcell-taps-swift/

This explains how to set up the segue to the second view controller, and pass the data you want to display.

Brief summary of the high points:

You will need to create a property in your secondVC to store the data you want to display:

```
class SecondViewController: UITableViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var Image: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Name: UITextField!
var information: Information?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

}

You can set up a "Show" segue in storyboard from your prototype table cell (in your first viewController) to the second viewController. Set the segue indentifier: "SecondViewController". When you press on a cell in the tableView, it will trigger the segue to show the second viewController, and call the prepare(for segue: _, *:*) function:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SecondViewController" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableview.indexPathForSelectedRow {
            let information = self.datasource[indexPath.row]
            if let secondVC = (segue.destination as? SecondViewController) {
                secondVC.information = info
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Work through the tutorial above, it should enable you to set up what you are trying to do. You will also learn where to find answers for any remaining questions.